# Deploy Java Beam pipeline through Dataflow Flex Template - How to pass proper pipeline config?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Java 11 Beam Pipeline that I'm trying to deploy to Dataflow via flex template.
I already have a `metadata.json` file which looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "environment",
        "label": "Environment on which to deploy. Controls which .conf file to load",
        "helpText": "Choose one of: development, staging, production",
        "isOptional": false,
        "regexes": [
          "^(development|staging|production)$"
        ],
        "paramType": "TEXT"
      }
    ],
  "sdkInfo": {
    "language": "JAVA"
  }
}
```

The pipeline reads config from a `<env>.conf` file through PureConfig.
I'd normally deploy it via Jenkins with this `environment` parameter, which would tell the pipeline to load `<env>.conf`, which also contains all the necessary dataflow config (num of workers, staging locations, etc)

The problem is: when I try to deploy the pipeline via the Dataflow UI by using a Flex Template, it seems as if it's not actually reading the configuration declared in `<env>.conf`, because dataflow is attempting to create new resources to store staging/temp files.

Am I missing something here? How should the config file be passed so that dataflow knows that the config of the pipeline is in it?

Comment: I don't quite follow the problem. When you run Flex Templates, your Docker container is invoked and the program to build the pipeline / graph is invoked, so you should be able to get the `environment` parameter there and define how that affects the job. I guess you are not using the `environment` parameter correctly? How are you using it to choose the right file?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the content of the **configuration file** as a parameter when deploying the Dataflow Flex Template. You can modify the process to include the configuration file content as a parameter by updating your **metadata.json** file. Add a new parameter to hold the content of the configuration file. For example:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "description": "bar",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "environment",
      "label": "Environment on which to deploy",
      "helpText": "Choose one of: development, staging, production",
      "isOptional": false,
      "regexes": [
        "^(development|staging|production)$"
      ],
      "paramType": "TEXT"
    },
    {
      "name": "configContent",
      "label": "Configuration content",
      "helpText": "Content of the configuration file",
      "isOptional": false,
      "regexes": [],
      "paramType": "TEXTAREA"
    }
  ],
  "sdkInfo": {
    "language": "JAVA"
  }
}
```

You will also need to parse the configuration from the provided content.

```
String configContent = options.getConfigContent();
Config config = parseConfig(configContent);
```

This code is an example when deploying the Flex Template. Provide the necessary parameters including the configContent parameter.

```
gcloud dataflow flex-template run my-dataflow-job \
  --template-file-gcs-location=gs://my-bucket/template.jar \
  --parameters=environment=production,configContent="$(< production.conf)"
```

`$(< production.conf)` reads the content of the production.conf file and passes it as the value for the configContent parameter.

Comment: Our pipeline was able to correctly select the configuration file based on the env value from the start. The issue was that the GCLOUD parameters were being passed as args to the application and this would either override values from our config or just straight up crash the pipeline due to a duplicate key. We fixed it by using PureConfig `withFallback` option to merge the two config sources (args and the conf file)